# Is there a R function for limiting the length of list elements?

Tags: r, list

I am struggling with a list manipulation in R right now. I have a list containing about 3000 elements, where each element is a character vector. The length of these character vectors is between 7 and 10.

I would like to manipulate this list in such a way, that those character vectors, that contain more than 7 elements, are limited to only the first 7 elements - hence drop the 8th, 9th, and 10th element/word/number of the respective character vector of the list.

Is there an easy way to do this? I hope you understand what I mean.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please share sample data with `dput`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is an auxiliary function that will shorten your vector.  Something like

```
shorten_vector <- function(y, max_length = 7){
  # NOTE: assumes that there are at least 7 elements in the vector.
  y[seq_len(max_length)]
}
```

you can then shorten the vectors in your list with

```
lapply(your_list, shorten_vector)
```

Or better

```
lapply(your_list, head, 7) # Thanks Moody
```

Reproducible example

```
# Make an object for an example.  A list of length 15
# where each element is a character vector between length 7 and 10

random_length <- sample(7:10, 15, replace = TRUE)

char_list <- 
  lapply(random_length,
         function(x){
           letters[seq_len(x)]
         })

# utility function
shorten_vector <- function(y, max_length = 7){
  y[seq_len(max_length)]
}


lapply(char_list,
       shorten_vector)
```

### Bonus

You said in a comment on Sonny's answer that you weren't really sure how the `lapply` worked. At it's conceptual core, `lapply` is a wrapper around a `for` loop.  The equivalent `for` loop would be

```
for(i in seq_along(char_list)){
  char_list[[i]] <- shorten_vector(char_list[[i]])
}

char_list
```

The `lapply` just handles the iteration limits for you and looks a little cleaner on the screen.

Comment: `shorten_vector` is `head` ;)

Comment: I know what it feels like :). They are not strictly equivalent in fact as `shorten_vector` will create `NA`s for elements shorter than 7, which I don't think OP expects.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `lapply` as below:

```
mylist <- list(a = c("a", "b"),
               b = c("a", "b", "c"))
mylist

$a
[1] "a" "b"

$b
[1] "a" "b" "c"

mylist2 <- lapply(mylist, function(x) {
      x[1:min(length(x), 2)]
    })
mylist2

$a
[1] "a" "b"

$b
[1] "a" "b"
```

Comment: Works perfectly fine, thank you so much!!! I guess I need to get used to the lapply functions, they are very useful. However, I do not fully understand them still as I am rather new to R.